# Proof ceiling function monotonicity

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

∀a,b∈R, a ≤ b ⇒ ⌈a⌉ ≤ ⌈b⌉,
This statement is true.
But if I go about proving it this way- -2.7 ≤ -2, then its ceiling -2 ≤ -2.
Is this a valid way to proof this statement or there are some technicalities I have left out??

Comment: Is showcasing that in one specific particular example of $-2.7\leq -2$ and $\lceil -2.7\rceil \leq \lceil -2\rceil$ happens to be true out of infinitely many possible examples enough proof that it happens to be true for all infinitely many examples?  No.

Comment: (starts singing)  Infinity bottles of beer on the wall, infinity bottles of beer... take one down, pass it around... still infinity bottles of beer on the wall! (repeat ad nauseum).  If you want to prove something is true for everything... showing it for only one or some is not good enough... You'd have to check it for each individually which is of course not possible.  You need to come up with a generic argument which checks it for *all* cases simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof, it is just an example that seems to support the argument.

In order to build a proof, you should start with the definition of the ceiling function: $\lceil a\rceil$ is the only integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n-1<a\le n$.

Using this definition, you can prove the statement by considering the different cases and playing with the inequalities.